# UIControl with transparent background

Tags: iphone, ios, uicontrol

I have a `UIControl` subclass. I use the following code the change it's background color:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill([self bounds]);
}
```

This works fine for all colors except `[UIColor clearColor]`. How can I make the background of the `UIControl` transparent?

Comment: Instead of `[UIColor clearColor]` have you tried `[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 andAlpha:0.0]`, I can't say why, but I once struggled with this case, when `[UIColor clearColor]` just didn't work..

Comment: I think alpha will gonna help you in that case

Comment: Do you set the `opaque` property to `NO` ?

Comment: I've tried both `[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0]` and setting `opaque` to `NO`. Both fill the background with black color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the a clear background color in the initWithFrame or/and initWithCoder

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

the default background of your control will be transparent, and you will then be able to fill any background color in the drawRect if you want.

The reason it doesn't work in your example is that the control have a default black background that is set somewhere ouside the drawRect (probably in the parent UIView init). When you set a colored background, it comes over the black one. When you set a clear one, you see the default black background.

Answer (score 3):

For a `UIControl` which is a subclass of `UIView`

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor <anycolor>];
```

should be sufficient, as @niko34 described, if you want the control to have a transparent color i.e. `[UIColor clearColor]` or any other color that has any kind of transparency you also need to set

```
self.opaque = NO;
```

otherwise any transparent color will be drawn in a nontransparent manner

Answer (score 0):

Try setting alpha to 0.5 or below and I think it should show a semi transparent background with a black tint like `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]`